# Retrieve immediate folder name if particular component is present using core services

Tags: 2013, core-service

I have a Main folder(mf) name as 030 Main, which has folders(f), subfolders(sf) and Components(c)like below.
mf- main foler,f- folder, c-component.
just to make simple, if c is present how should i get immediate f name(i.e folder name).

For example like below

100 Africa(f)-->110 Somalia(sf)-->010 Play(c),020 overview(c),030 Beach(c)
120 India(f) -->110 Pune(sf) -->010 Play(c),020 Station(c),030 Fishing(c)
120 India(f) -->110 Kerala(sf) -->010 Play(c),020 Station(c),030 Beach(c),040 flight(c)

There are also some components within 030 Main.

Now I want to retrieve some content only from Beach components. Along with it i want immediate subfolder name.i.e(if beach is present need respective city names also like somalia,kerala). I tried below, First used component filter and then fetched all the components, then checked for" 030 Beach " then get content.
Now i want folder name which has " 030 Beach " component.

```
OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
            filter.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component };
            filter.Recursive = true;

 foreach (var id in client.GetListXml(folder, filter).Elements().ToList())
              {
                  string compTitle=id.Attribute("Title").Value;
                  string compId = id.Attribute("ID").Value;

                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  if (compTitle.Equals("030 Beach"))
                  {

                       ComponentData component1 = client.Read(compId, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
                        var componentContent = component1.Content;
```

}

Comment: Hi Rachel, In your question I am not able to see exact issue you are facing. Can you edit your question to specify the issue you are facing.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to classify resorts by the facilities they have. This might be easier to do using Keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you get the `ComponentData` object you can access the property `LocationInfo` to access the repository object (`Folder`) where the component is located

You can retrieve the folder name by adding this line to you code:

```
string componentsOrganizationalItem = component1.LocationInfo.OrganizationalItem.Title;
```